# outline vectorshape algorithm

Tags: algorithm, vector-graphics

consider the red line to be given as a sequence of points

[image]

I'm looking for an algorithm to create the outlines of the thick black shape (also as a sequence of points) such that they are ordered cleanly. And the outline should also respect a minimum distance to itself.

What algorithm can I use to achieve this?

Comment: What is the criteria for the outer shape?

Comment: it should be a clean line (no points of the outline should lie somewhere on the black area in the picture, but only on it's border)

Comment: @Mat - I think @Apalala's question was, what is the relationship between the red line and the black border? Without knowing how they are related, it's impossible to define an algorithm to generate one from the other.

Comment: ah - i see. the black border keeps a constant minimumdistance to the redline. and it keeps another minimumdistance to any other black outline. the distanceconstraint to other black outlines dominates over the red line constraint

Comment: As far as the black-black rule is concerned, the minimumdistance does obviously not fully describe what you have in mind (Why does it not apply for e.g. the inner-upper corner of your shape?  What about neighboring points--they are very likely to fall below the minimum distance?).  Could you further quantify the black-black rule?

Comment: ok - the simples description would be like this: the black area is a "thick" version of the red line of diameter 'width' & any straight line perpendicular to a tangent of the red line must not cross black area longer than 'width'. background: i want to create a 'racetrack' from a given route and if this route comes close to itself somewhere, there must be a "wall" inbetween. And the whole thing must be a clean vectorshape.

Comment: Is this for something like [raceline machining](http://powermill.com/general/hsm.asp)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need two types of [offsetting algorithms](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=offset%20algorithm):

1. Offset a curve in both directions to produce a track
2. Offset a closed curve inwards to produce one or more smaller closed polygons.

Let r be the distance to the red line, and b the desired thickness of the wall between the black lines/tracks.

- Offset the red line by r using algorithm 1. This may produce a track which overlaps itself, i.e. has "blob-like" areas.
- Offset the red line inwards using algorithm 2. Use binary search to find the distance d at which the shape splits in two or disappears. If d > b, then offset inwards by d - b to produce the second area. Otherwise the algorithm fails.
- Subtract the second area from the first.